# Bring div element to front with zindex in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having the hardest time getting this to work. I went from an async event handler to the current function. Currently what ends up happening is if you select an element that is last in the parent div it ends up having the same zIndex, still having the other element placed on top.

I'm basically trying to make sure my if statement makes sure the element I click ends up having the the highest zIndex. This is my whole component code, the main function to look at is `onStart`. I'm leaving it a mess in hopes someone can understand what I'm trying to accomplish and help me out:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
import Router from 'next/router'


import {
  BrowserFrame, 
  DragHandle,
  BrowserContent 
} from './styles'

class DesktopBrowser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      highestIndex: 0
    }
  }

  findHighestZIndex(elem) {

    let elems = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);


    let highest = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      let zindex =document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null)
      .getPropertyValue("z-index");

      if ((zindex > highest) && (zindex != 'auto')) {

        this.setState({
          highestIndex: zindex
        })

      }

    }




  }

  onStart(e) {

    this.findHighestZIndex("react-draggable")


    if(this.state.highestIndex >= 0) {
      console.log('greater than zero', this.state.highestIndex, e.currentTarget.style.zIndex)
      e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = (+this.state.highestIndex) + (+1)
      this.setState({
        highestIndex: (+e.currentTarget.style.zIndex) + 1
      })
    } else if (this.state.highestIndex < e.currentTarget.style.zIndex) {
      console.log('lower')
      e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = (+this.state.highestIndex) + (+2)
    } else {
      console.log('catch')
    }

    // if(this.state.highestIndex >= 0) {

    //   this.setState({
    //     highestIndex: (+this.state.highestIndex) + 1
    //   })

    //   e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = (+this.state.highestIndex) + 1
    //   console.log(e.currentTarget.style.zIndex)

    // } 


  }




  render() {
   return (
      <Draggable 
        bounds="body"
        handle=".drag-handle"
        onStart={this.onStart.bind(this)}
        defaultPosition={
          {
            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].offsetWidth - 1000)), 
            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].offsetHeight - 500)) 
          }
        }>
      <BrowserFrame>
        <DragHandle className="drag-handle" />
        <BrowserContent bg={this.props.content.image}>
          <button onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            Router.push(`/portfolio/${this.props.content.slug}`)
          }}>View</button>
        </BrowserContent>

      </BrowserFrame>
      </Draggable>
    )
  }
}

export default DesktopBrowser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're always setting `this.state.highestIndex` and the `zIndex` of the current target to be the same in the first `if()` statement. So when the `else if()` statement runs it is always false.

See commented code below.

```
    if(this.state.highestIndex >= 0) { // This is always going to be true!!
      console.log('greater than zero', this.state.highestIndex, e.currentTarget.style.zIndex)
      e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = (+this.state.highestIndex) + (+1)// Now you're setting the zIndex of the current target to higher than this.state.highestIndex 
      this.setState({
        highestIndex: (+e.currentTarget.style.zIndex) + 1 // And now setting highestIndex to be identical to current target's zIndex.
      })
    } else if (this.state.highestIndex < e.currentTarget.style.zIndex) { // Now this will never be true because you set them equal in the first if block.
      console.log('lower')
      e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = (+this.state.highestIndex) + (+2)
    } else {
      console.log('catch')
    }
```

You probably want something like this (untested)

```
    if(this.state.highestIndex >= 0) { // This is always going to be true!!
      e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = this.state.highestIndex + 2 // Add 2
      this.setState({
        highestIndex: this.state.highestIndex++; // Increment highestIndex by 1.
      }) // Now current target has a zIndex 1 higher than the rest
    } else {
      console.log('catch')
    }
```

But really that's potentially a bad solution as well because eventually zIndex could max out and thus it would no longer work. It would be better to just set all elements zIndex to 1 and then set the current target's to a higher value. Resetting them each time. Something along these lines maybe (removing your function to find the highest zIndex and the setState calls).

```
onStart(e) {
  let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('react-draggable');
  for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.zIndex = 1;
    e.currentTarget.style.zIndex = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your way is much better haha. I overthought the situation. Thanks!